# Supersymmetry particles in cosmic ray showers

Tags: supersymmetry, cosmic-rays

Antimatter was first discovered in cosmic ray debris.  Why haven't we found the heavy supersymmetry particles in cosmic ray debris?

Comment: [It's been suggested](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.55.469)

Comment: Could be that SUSY is not an experimentally realizable theory.  Theyve seen no SUSY at CERN either

Comment: The problem is simply technological: one can't make a detector big enough to collect enough of these rare events and to distinguish them from background. The entire architecture of high energy physics detectors relies on the fact that the events happen in a very well defined interaction point (it's volume, really).